# Progress Step Indicator in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am starting a project in QT with QML and I need to build a progress indicator to show the steps of a process. I wish to do something like the image in that link: https://dribbble.com/shots/10261597-Progress-Indicator

I coundn't found nothing in the documentation about that, what is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Qt doesn't have a progress bar like that you should create it by yourself. which means Qt doesn't have a class like that.

Comment: you can inherit [QProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprogressbar.html) and by overriding [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprogressbar.html#paintEvent) function , Create your custom `ProgressBar`

Comment: Thank you @Parisa.H.R I will search about that class and functions.

Comment: You can easily create such a control in QML in half an hour, the documentation search will take longer. That's the beauty of this language.